Salesforce CLI - Husky - Git - 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command
I am building a pre commit code that run dry run with the staged files to the target org.
Everything was working fine until if there are any spaces in the staged file inside the force-app.
pre-commit file code in husky
STAGED_FILES=$(git diff --name-only --cached | grep "^force-app/" | sed 's/.*/"&"/' | paste -sd "," -)
set -e
echo "STAGED_FILES: $STAGED_FILES"
if [ -n "$STAGED_FILES" ]; then
    echo "Generating manifest..."
    MANIFEST_OUTPUT=$(sf project generate manifest --output-dir ./manifest -p "$STAGED_FILES" || true)
............................

Error:
STAGED_FILES: "force-app/main/default/flexipages/Account_Record_Page_WCC.flexipage-meta.xml","force-app/main/default/layouts/Account-Account Layout.layout-meta.xml" Generating manifest... 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
Note that if there are no spaces in the staged files, then its working as expected.

I have tried changing the environment variables to C:\PROGRA~1 but no luck.
Wrapped each file with single quotes, double quotes, back tick but again no luck.
Tried wrapping up $STAGED_FILES with ',", and without quotes too, but no use.

